# What will be the total duration and cost of Annapurna Base Camp trek?

Tags: trekking, nepal, himalayas

I am from Nepal, but living in India.
I will be visiting Nepal this year during Dashain and am planning to do the ABC trek in early October this year (2016).
The plan is to complete the trek in at most 6 days, trekking 8-9 hrs a day.
I know this is quite a task, but I have read in few blogs ([one link here](http://www.detourista.com/blog/annapurna-base-camp-trek-diy/)) that it is possible and I am quite sure of walking for such long as I have walked on Nepal mountains for such long hours on many occasions (distance: 18-20 km, time: 5-6hrs with no or 1-2kg backpack, and 8-9hrs with 7-8kg backpack, Elevation 600m to 1300m).

The itinerary I have prepared is as follows:

> Day 1: Leave Pokhara early morning. Reach Nayapul. Trek to Ghandruk
>   by evening.
>
> Day 2: Ghandruk -> Sinuwa/Bamboo.
>
> Day 3: Sinuwa/Bamboo -> MBC.
>
> Day 4: MBC -> ABC -> MBC -> Bamboo.
>
> Day 5: Bamboo -> Jhinu Danda.
>
> Day 6: Jhinu Danda -> Phedi -> Pokhara.

The actual stoppages and route may vary, but it should be done in 6 days.

Also I have estimated the expenses for each day as below:

> Lunch : 400, Dinner : 400, Accommodation : 200 = 1000 NPR per day.

I am aware that as we go higher, the food becomes expensive, but I have taken an average cost of the food (ex. 300 per plate at lower elevations and 500 per plate at higher elevations).
I am a minimalist and Dal-Bhat-Tarkaari will be enough for me.
I will be carrying something to eat for breakfast with me (biscuits, chiura or flattened rice, candies and noodles) and I don't drink tea, so no expenses for breakfast on the trek.
I will be drinking water from local taps (springs/dhaaras) as I am used to it.

The *total cost for 6 days is estimated to be 6000 NPR* (of course I will be keeping extra cash for emergency).

I just want to verify if the above estimate, both number of days and expenses, is correct or not and if there is something that I have missed to take into account.
Considering the short duration of the trek, if anywhere I feel that lack of oxygen (AMS) is affecting me, I will undoubtedly back out from the trek and turn back immediately.

Answer (score 7):

**Duration**

Is it feasible in six days? Certainly. Is if feasible for you in six days? That depends on you.

In general the organised treks will take a few days longer than what you propose. But those are meant to be accessible for overweight, middle aged, European coach potatoes. If you are in reasonable physical shape, six days is fine. If you are really fit and sporty you could even go for four days (or even less). But why hurry? From your description it sounds like six days will be a good option for you.

For such an elevation AMS is rather rare. You would have to be unlucky to get it. But if you develop symptoms you should turn back and descend. You stated so much yourself, but I like to reiterate it because we are talking about a potentially life-threatening situation. Being short of breath in the higher parts is no problem and is even a given.

**Cost**

I think your estimate is possible if you live frugally, but will be close to the limit for two meals + night. The cost is usually in the food, rather than the nights.

I came across a [blogpost](http://www.my-travel-experience.com/article/nepal/annapurna_circuit_ultimate_guide/) that gives a nice overview on prices on the Annapurna Circuit (not the Sanctuary trek but it is similar there) in the different villages in 2015. Scroll down towards the end just above the title "How to get there" on that page.

You will see that with two meals a day you get quickly to your scheduled budget and even will pass it on the higher parts. Personally, I would rather budget 1500NPR/day and be happy that I manage to stay below budget than having to worry every meal about the total cost.

In the Khumbu I once entered a place that had on the outside a small sign saying "Nepali Hotel". It turned out to be a place where guides and porters were staying. It was very basic with everybody sleeping in one big bunk and as a meal the choice between dal-bhat, only dal or only bhat. So no choice at all. Needless to say the cost was a fraction of what I paid in a real lodge. I assume that similar accommodation exists in the Annapurna region. But for a white Caucasian, obviously tourist, it is hard to find. You, as a Nepali, might have more luck. Socializing with guides and porters might save you some money in this way. Those guys know the valley, have been there a zillion times and might send you to places where they would not send a Western tourist.

Other costs you might be forgetting:

- Transportation to Nayapul: [wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Annapurna_Sanctuary) states 110-200NPR for the bus Pokhara-Nayapul. For both ways count on a total transportation cost of 400NPR.
- Trekking permit: the [NTNC website](http://www.ntnc.org.np/trekking-annapurna-gaurishankar-and-manaslu-information-and-entry-permit-forms) states a fee of 200NPR for SAARC citizens. I could not find any exception for Nepali citizens, so that appears to be the fee that will apply to you.

Comment: Thanks mate. The link to the blog was very useful. And yes, I am aware of the TIMS and ACAP permit required. I wanted to get the estimate of just the food and accommodation.